# Syntax error on ci model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just have a small problem with my Insert Into Query with codeigniter for some reason it is saying `syntax error check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version`. I thought I did every thing correct looks OK to me but not sure.

I thought could do it this way.

```
public function database() {
$data['db_prefix'] = $this->db->dbprefix; $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username'); $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email'); $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password'); 

$this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . $data['db_prefix'] . "user` WHERE user_id = '1'");

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . $data['db_prefix'] . "user` SET user_id = '1', user_group_id = '1', username = '" . $this->db->escape($data['username']) . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', status = '1', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', date_added = NOW()");
}
```

Comment: Please reformat you code so its readable.

Comment: maybe one of the columns is a keyword? Try surrounding all columns with backticks

Comment: Your insert syntax is wrong. Use: INSERT INTO table VALUES ...

Comment: Do you mean like an array format

Comment: INSERT INTO
    `users` (`name`, `age`, `country`, `city`)
VALUES
    ('Evgen', 26, 'Russia', 'Ryazan')

Comment: @Phantom INSERT SET is valid, btw: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status` is a reserved word in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html

Wrap `status` in the `INSERT` query with ``

```
$this->db->query("
    INSERT INTO 
       `" . $data['db_prefix'] . "user` 
    SET 
         user_id       = '1', 
         user_group_id = '1', 
         username      = '" . $this->db->escape($data['username']) . "',  
         salt          = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', 
         password      = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', 

         `status`      = '1', 

         email         = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', 
         date_added    = NOW()

");
```

Comment: I thought it worked but now still saying You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin'', salt = ''47f256d74'', password = '' at line 6 I use codeigniter